# UISwitch still slightly visible in UITableViewCell after table editing is complete

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, editing, uiswitch

I have a strange issue with the `editingAccessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell` still showing after the table editing mode is switched off.

Currently I am using a `UISwitch` as the editing accessory view and letting the table view handle moving the editing view on/off screen with animation when the navigation bar's edit button is pressed.

Almost all of the editing accessory views animate correctly off screen, but there are always two that don't quite make it off screen and then they get reused when the cell is dequeued and reused so they show up during scrolling.

Has anyone else seen this or is there something I am missing here?

I am setting up the cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AllStatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AllStatCell"];

    if (cell.editingAccessoryView == nil) {
        UISwitch *statSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [statSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(saveSwitchState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.editingAccessoryView = statSwitch;
    }

    NSString *statName = [self statNameForIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.statName.text = statName;
    [(UISwitch *)cell.editingAccessoryView setOn:[self switchValueForIndexPath:indexPath withStatNamed:statName]];

    if (tableView.editing) cell.statValue.hidden = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

I have tried overriding the `setEditing` method to reload the table data after a delay to allow for the animations to complete, but it only works sometimes

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // Insert/delete the stat rows depending on editing mode
    [self rebuildTableDataAnimated:YES];

    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // Trying to fix bug that shows part of a UISwitch on screen still even though editing mode is completed
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Here's a screen shot:

[image: Bug image]

Comment: My first try would be to reload the table after you've performed the editing.

Comment: @flexaddicted Unfortunately that did not work

Comment: Sorry, I did't see it. What about reload it like `[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES]; [tableView reloadData];`? Do you perform some calculation in background?

Comment: In addition you could just try (for test purposes) to use your own bool property for seeing if the table is in edit mode or not and check against this. e.g. `if (isEditingMode) cell.statValue.hidden = YES;`

Comment: Nothing quite works as it should.  I ended up finding a fix for it, but it feels like such a hack.  I just set the cell's editing accessory view to nil if we are no longer in editing mode and then I reload the data

Comment: See my answer below for some code on it, hoping someone has a better method.

Comment: Maybe the error is inside `-(void)rebuildTableDataAnimated`? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like such a hack, so hopefully someone else has a better fix for it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AllStatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AllStatCell"];

    NSString *statName = [self statNameForIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Hack fix for a bug that shows part of a UISwitch on screen still even though editing mode is completed
    // Configure stat on/off switches
    cell.editingAccessoryView = [self cellEditingAccessoryViewForEditing:tableView.editing];
    if (tableView.editing) [(UISwitch *)cell.editingAccessoryView setOn:[self switchValueForIndexPath:indexPath withStatNamed:statName]];

    cell.statName.text = statName;
    [cell.statValue setHidden:tableView.editing];

    return cell;
}

// Hack fix for a bug that shows part of a UISwitch on screen still even though editing mode is completed
- (UISwitch *)cellEditingAccessoryViewForEditing:(BOOL)tableIsEditing
{
    if (tableIsEditing) {
        UISwitch *statSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [statSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(saveSwitchState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        return statSwitch;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but having the same problem in Xcode 7 with a UIStepper. My solution was to embed it in a UIView with some padding on the left and right, then set the parent view to the editingAccessoryView. It works, and is less of a hack.